# MVC best way to show a splash screen on initial load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a method where if it is initial load then a cookie will be set and it will direct to a splash screen.

After about 4 seconds I need the html to redirect back to the view where the cookie has been set and show go to the main page. The problem is after 4 seconds it just reloads the page and the splash animation keeps happening. I need it to go back to the homecontroller so that the cookie method is processed

Is there a best practice way to do this? Splash screen is required per requirements.

In my homecontroller

```cs
public virtual IActionResult Index()
{
    string splash = "splash"
    var splashKey = _httpContextAccessor.HttpCOntext.Request.Cookies["key"]

    if (Request.Cookies[splash] != null)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        SetCookie(splash);

        return Redirect(Url.Content(Url.Content("`/Content/mysplash.html"));
    }
}
```

my splash html

```
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>

   splashstufff
</head>
<body>
<script>

    setTimeout(function() { window.location = "http://localhost:4200/" }, 4000);   <----Just loops here no redirect happens

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you like to redirect the user back and forth, only to display a splash screen?

Comment: As stated in the intial post these are the requirements. Now if it is at all possible that the splash screen can show and then fade out to show the homepage after a few seconds then please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can add an absolute element that will cover the whole screen and fade it out when needed, showing the page underneath

For example

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.splashscreen').fadeOut();
}, 4000);
```

```css
.splashscreen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.splashscreen h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="splashscreen">
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p> Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Pellentesque egestas, neque sit amet convallis pulvinar, justo nulla eleifend augue, ac auctor orci leo non est. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Sed
      a libero.
    </p>
    <p>
      Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Cras dapibus. Morbi mollis tellus ac sapien. Duis vel nibh at velit scelerisque suscipit. Morbi nec metus.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can put something fancier in the `splashscreen` div, like a spinner or similar.